# Bluebook support in Latex?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, legal-style

I need to write a paper conforming with the [blue book standards](https://www.legalbluebook.com/).

Has there been any move on creating packages that support blue book-style formatting and citations? Or should I get ready to do a bunch of work on my own `bibtex` and `article` classes?

If the latter, are there modern alternatives to `bibtex`? Are there any specific modern approaches to customised article classes?

Comment: In my experience the number of LaTeX users in the legal field (even in academia) is vanishingly small.  There is a very powerful alternative to `bibtex` in the `biber+biblatex` combination, but I don't think anyone has tackled this particular problem.  Legal citations are informationally quite different from other academic citations (even those in the Humanities).  But if the standards are well described, it should be possible to create some `biblatex` styles for them.  See [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/2693) for more information on `biblatex`.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks, I will check those out. I'm only using latex because I'm a transplanted software engineer in the world of law. Still amazes me that people use WP software they hate.

Comment: One other comment. You're kind of conflating two separate issues in your question: citation/bibliography styles are logically independent of document classes. If there are other formatting requirements (such as specific sectioning styles) that are not related to  citations, you might want to ask a separate question about that.  The answers might be easier to come by too. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn Unless I'm mistaken, the Blue Book also lays down some more substantive formatting guides than just citations.

Comment: Yes, I figured that, but from the point of view of the site it's usually better to ask separate questions for distinct issues.  So you should ask  non-citation related formatting questions separately.

Comment: @AlanMunn Ah cool. I'll look at what the substantive bits are before asking my next question.

Comment: More than 6 years later, I would still love to have a resource like this! like many legal tasks though, I guess I should be grateful it's so complicated to computerize that it still makes sense to pay lawyers.

Comment: I realize this is an old post but would love to hear if there are any updates on the matter? That is: 1) Anyway to import a bibtex library using Bluebook citation; 2) Anyway to incorporate the Bluebook citation into the body of the article (same as for instance in Econ...) [I use Jabref but if something is better for this purpose I would appreciate learning! Thanks!]

Comment: @Julie I don't think there's anything more that has happened since. My original comment still stands: there really don't seem to be enough LaTeX users in the legal world for someone to have created such a package.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yeah, I think I just solved this by not using LaTeX

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know of any Bluebook style, and I *think* I would if it existed. Given the [notorious complexities](http://yalelawjournal.org/the-yale-law-journal/content-pages/the-bluebook-blues/) of the Bluebook it would have to be a biblatex project, and it would be quite a project! In the common law world, I know there is a written-and-working-but-unreleased version of the McGill style for Canadian authorities, there's a partially compete [Australian style](http://willhardy.com.au/aglc-and-latex/), and there's an English style based on [OSCOLA](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/oscola), which is on CTAN. None of them is Bluebook conformant. The one that I think is closest to complete (which is OSCOLA -- but (disclaimer!) I wrote it so I suffer parental bias) might provide a start -- but it would only be a sort of "inspiration" start, rather than a "much of the legwork is done" start: also it's hardly a stable package.

Implementation of a subset of the Bluebook (say books, articles, cases and perhaps the Constitution and USC) wouldn't probably be too much of a struggle. Implementing the whole thing would be a mammoth task. How mammoth would depend on how far you sought to automate things like abbreviations, cite signals, citation order and the like.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll take a look. I'm looking at this for a specific paper, which will probably reference articles, US statutes, US cases, non-US cases, non-US statutes, and arbitration awards. Whatever I produce will probably only deal with those.

Comment: If I can help in any way, I'd be happy to. Just a warning: I discovered my email in the OSCOLA documentation is wrong! Just pstanley not p.stanley. What a typo ...

Comment: Thank you! I'll tackle the issue, then let you know if I have any questions.

Comment: In the end...I just used Word, and did the citations by hand. Ho hum.

Comment: @PaulStanley -- Do you have any more information regarding the status of the McGill style? I have begun to write a McGill style for my own needs, but it is very much *ad hoc* and therefore incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Lawtex?  I just found it https://sourceforge.net/projects/lawtex/
I don't think it has been recently improved but I think it is a good starting point for anyone who want to develop further. Perhaps somebody familiar with Bluebook can tell us what is missing or incorrect.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Now in 2020 packages with current maintenance and Bluebook support include:

`biblatex-chicago`:  see CTAN

`lawcite`:  see [lawcite on GitHub](https://github.com/texcicada/lawcite)