# Is there a way to move the "year" to the back of a footnote citation, placing the "page" right before it?

Tags: biblatex, legal-style

The reason I want to do it is that the Bluebook style for American legal academica requires it. But I haven't been able to find out on how to do it. I have moved close to the desired *Bluebook* result departing from [Will Hardy's](http://willhardy.com.au/aglc-and-latex/) *Australian Guide to Legal Citation 2 or AGLC2*.

According to the *Bluebook*, the citation of articles and books should finish with the year they were published between brackets. So, for instance:

**Article**:

Author, *Title of the article*. 4 Harv. L. Rev 93, 98[this is the page] (year)

**Book** [all in Small Caps]:

Author, Title of the Book [page] (year)

The files I use are the following:

- [Will Hardy's ALC2](http://willhardy.com.au/aglc-and-latex/) (aglc2.bbx and aglc2.cbx)
- A biblatex.cfg which looks like this (I think it is relevant for my question).

Biblatex.cfg:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
{title}{\emph{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
[book]
{title}{\sc{#1\isdot}}

\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
{journaltitle}{\sc{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
\printfield{volume}
\usebibmacro{journal}%
\setunit*{\addspace}%
\newunit}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
\clearfield{day}%
\clearfield{month}%
\clearfield{endday}%
\clearfield{endmonth}%
\clearfield{shorttitle}%
}

\endinput
```

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber, sortlocale=auto, style=aglc2, citestyle=aglc2]{biblatex}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\addbibresource{america2.bib}

\begin{document}

This paper is an example of how footnotes should work in \emph{Bluebook}, the 
style of citation used in American legal academia. We call authors such as Friedman, 
who we think is awesome.\footcite[578]{friedman1} And we think he is awesome  again.\footcite[578]{friedman1}

And we cite him again.\footcite[578]{friedman1} But then we move on and cite some 
other guy for ``a new jurisprudence of judicial restraint.''\footcite{balkin}

Some other guy gets cited \footcite{kurland} and then we cite Friedman again
but with another article.\footcite{friedman2} But then we cite a book.\footcite[22]{parker}

And we cite Kurland again\footcite{kurland}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Sorry I didn't include, before, america2.bib:

```
@article{friedman1,
    title = {Dialogue and Judicial Review},
    volume = {91},
    issn = {00262234},
    url = {},
    doi = {10.2307/1289700},
    pages = {577},
    number = {4},
    journaltitle = {Michigan Law Review},
    author = {Friedman, Barry},
    urldate = {2014-06-03},
    date = {1993-02},
    file = {}
}

@book{parker,
    title = {Here, the People Rule: A Constitutional Populist Manifesto},
    volume = {},
    url = {},
    shorttitle = {Here, the People Rule},
    pages = {},
    journaltitle = {},
    shortjournal = {},
    author = {Parker, Richard D.},
    date = {1992},
    file = {}
}

@article{friedman2,
    title = {Importance of Being Positive: The Nature and Function of Judicial Review, The},
    volume = {72},
    url = {},
    shorttitle = {Importance of Being Positive},
    pages = {1257},
    journaltitle = {University of Cincinnati Law Review},
    shortjournal = {U. Cin. L. Rev.},
    author = {Friedman, Barry},
    date = {2003},
    file = {}
}

@article{kurland,
    title = {The Supreme Court, 1963 Term},
    volume = {78},
    issn = {{0017811X}},
    url = {},
    doi = {10.2307/1338853},
    pages = {143},
    number = {1},
    journaltitle = {Harvard Law Review},
    author = {Kurland, Philip B.},
    urldate = {2014-06-03},
    date = {1964-11},
    file = {}
}

@article{balkin,
    title = {Understanding the Constitutional Revolution},
    volume = {87},
    url = {},
    pages = {1045},
    journaltitle = {Virginia Law Review},
    shortjournal = {Va. L. Rev.},
    author = {Balkin, Jack M. and Levinson, Sanford},
    date = {2001},
    file = {}
}
```

Comment: To test, it would be nice to have `america2.bib`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out --- I've edited it and included it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way, using `xpatch`. I deleted the `shorttitle` fields, as you don't seem to use them, and they appeared inconsistently in the footnotes (duplicates ot the full title, just before the year).

Let me also mention  [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71306/bluebook-support-in-latex), which you may know, in relation with translating the Bluebook specifications in a bib(la)tex style file.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sortlocale=auto, style=aglc2, citestyle=aglc2]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro*{bracketsyear}{%
\iffieldundef{year}
{\setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock}%
{\printfield[brackets]{year}%
\setunit*{\addspace}}}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{article}{%
\setunit{\space}\newblock
\printfield{pages}%
\setunit{\space}\newblock}
{%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock
\printfield{pages}%
\setunit{\space}\newblock
\usebibmacro{bracketsyear}%
}{}{}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
\scshape
\usebibmacro{bibindex}%
\usebibmacro{author/editor}%
\setunit{\space}\newblock%
\printfield{postnote}
\usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock%
\printfield{postnote}
%\iffieldundef{url}{\printfield{note}\newunit\newblock}{}%
\usebibmacro{edition+year}%
% \newunit\newblock%
% \usebibmacro{origtitle}%
% \setunit{}%
% \iffieldundef{postnote}{}{\nopunct}%
}

\xpatchbibmacro{journal+issuetitle}{%
 \usebibmacro{parensyear}%
    }
{}{}{}

\renewbibmacro*{edition+year}{%
\addspace[\setunit{}%
\ifnameundef{translator}{}{\printnames{translator} trans\addcomma\addspace}%
\iffieldundef{note}{}{first published \printfield{note}\addcomma\addspace}%
\iffieldundef{edition}
{\printfield{year}}%
{\printfield{edition}\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}\printfield{year}}%
]}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
 {\bibsentence
 \usebibmacro{prenote}}
 {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
 \usebibmacro{cite}}
 {\multicitedelim}
 {}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\addbibresource{america2.bib}

\begin{document}

This paper is an example of how footnotes should work in \emph{Bluebook}, the
style of citation used in American legal academia. We call authors such as Friedman,
who we think is awesome.\footcite[578]{friedman1} And we think he is awesome again.\footcite[578]{friedman1}

And we cite him again.\footcite[578]{friedman1} But then we move on and cite some
other guy for ``a new jurisprudence of judicial restraint.''\footcite{balkin}

Some other guy gets cited \footcite{kurland} and then we cite Friedman again
but with another article.\footcite{friedman2} But then we cite a book.\footcite[22]{parker}

And we cite Kurland again\footcite{kurland}, and Parker again. \footcite[22]{parker}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]